# EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE error while using GlSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, glsurfaceview, easyar

I have app with AR functionality and I'm using EasyAR lib for ar and GLSurfaceView for camera preview. When android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in my app it works correctly, but when I switch it to true, I have "white noise" in my preview screen and this errors:

```
eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
eglQueryContext(2122): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)

updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x500
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glEnable:4892
GL error 0x500 condition
[!GLESv2Validation::allowedEnable(ctx->majorVersion(), ctx->minorVersion(), what)]

device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glEnable:4892                                                                                                    GL error 0x500 condition
[!GLESv2Validation::allowedEnable(ctx->majorVersion(), ctx->minorVersion(), what)]

eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
tid 27715: eglQueryContext(2122): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Comment: The error message eglQueryContext 32c0 EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE indicates that the EasyAR library is trying to query a context attribute that is not supported by the GPU. This can happen for a variety of reasons, but it is often caused by a bug in the EasyAR library itself.